# Python - How can I fit a curve to a function that contains a numerically calculated integral?

Tags: python, curve-fitting, numerical-methods, numerical-integration

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as spi
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math as mh

def GUFunction(z, Omega_Lambda):
    integral = spi.quad(lambda zvar: AuxIntegrandum(zvar, Omega_Lambda), 0.0, z)[0]
    DL = (1+z) * c/H0 * integral *1000000
    return (5*(mh.log(DL,10)-1))

def AuxIntegrandum(z, Omega_Lambda):
    Omega_m = 1 - Omega_Lambda

    return 1 / mh.sqrt(Omega_m*(1+z)**3 + Omega_Lambda)

def DataFit(filename):
    print curve_fit(GUFunction, ComputeData(filename)[0], ComputeData(filename)[1])

DataFit("data.dat")
```

data.dat has z values in the first column and GUF(z) values in the second column.

Upon executing this code, the compiler tells me that comparing an array to a value (+inf or -inf) is ambiguous.
I think this refers to the integration boundaries, where it looks to see if I want to integrate to infinity. For some reason it apparently puts all z-values from the data file into the integration boundary.
Is there some trick I don't know about which allows you to fit a curve to a numerically integrated function?

Here's the exact error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot.py", line 83, in <module>
    DataFit("data.dat")
  File "plot.py", line 67, in DataFit
    print curve_fit(GUFunction, ComputeData(filename)[0], ComputeData(filename)[1])
  File "/home/joshua/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 736, in curve_fit
    res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
  File "/home/joshua/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 377, in leastsq
    shape, dtype = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)
  File "/home/joshua/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 26, in _check_func
    res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
  File "/home/joshua/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 454, in func_wrapped
    return func(xdata, *params) - ydata
  File "plot.py", line 57, in GUFunction
    integral = spi.quad(lambda zvar: AuxIntegrandum(zvar, Omega_Lambda), 0.0, z)[0]
  File "/home/joshua/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 323, in quad
    points)
  File "/home/joshua/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py", line 372, in _quad
    if (b != Inf and a != -Inf):
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Comment: You aren't explicitly making a comparison anywhere so it must be in one of the libraries code, probably paste in the exact error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: `curve_fit` tries to evaluate the target function on an array of xdata, but `quad` cannot accept a vector argument. You need to define your target function via e.g. a list comprehension over an input array.

Let's cook up a minimum reproducible example:

```
In [33]: xdata = np.linspace(0, 3, 11)

In [34]: ydata = xdata**3

In [35]: def integr(x):
    ...:     return quad(lambda t: t**2, 0, x)[0]
    ...: 

In [36]: def func(x, a):
    ...:     return integr(x) * a
    ...: 

In [37]: curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-4660c65f85a2> in <module>()
----> 1 curve_fit(func, xdata, ydata)

 [... removed for clarity ...]

~/virtualenvs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/integrate/quadpack.py in _quad(func, a, b, args, full_output, epsabs, epsrel, limit, points)
    370 def _quad(func,a,b,args,full_output,epsabs,epsrel,limit,points):
    371     infbounds = 0
--> 372     if (b != Inf and a != -Inf):
    373         pass   # standard integration
    374     elif (b == Inf and a != -Inf):

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Which is precisely the error you're seeing. Ok, the error comes from `quad`, which tries to evaluate `func(xdata, a)`, which boils down to `integr(xdata)` and that does not work. (How I found it out? I put `import pdb; pdf.set_trace()` inside the `func` function and poked around in the debugger).

Then, let's make the target function handle array arguments:

```
In [38]: def func2(x, a):
    ...:     return np.asarray([integr(xx) for xx in x]) * a
    ...: 

In [39]: curve_fit(func2, xdata, ydata)
Out[39]: (array([ 3.]), array([[  3.44663413e-32]]))
```

Comment: Thanks! This eventually worked, though apparently math and numpy don't work nicely together so I had to replace mh.log(DL,10) by np.log10(), else it would complain again.